# How to decipher a sqoop import statement?

Tags: oracle, hadoop, sqoop

I've been reading about sqoop import and there always seemed to be a login and a password, but then I saw this thing

```
sqoop import \
-Dmapreduce.job.queuename=queue \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:WRH/WRH@//biis1:1111/UAT \
--query"select col from etl.stg@etl2 AND \$CONDITIONS"  \
--target-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/db.db/dim_pro \
--delete-target-dir \
-m 1 \
--fields-terminated-by '\t'
```

I think that WRH stands for password and login(but I am not sure) and I have no idea what this

```
@//biis1:1111/UAT
```

means.

Comment: `@//host_name:port_number/service_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, WRH is mentioned for the username and password.

@//biis1:1111/UAT : The ip address of the machine on which oracle is installed and the port along with the database to fetch the data.